# Something with my code that I cannot seem to figure out

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DNA{
  public static void main(String [] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the dna string?");
   StringBuilder DNA  = new StringBuilder(scan.nextLine());
   DNA.append( scan.nextLine());
    for(int i=0;i<DNA.length();i++){
      if(DNA.charAt(i)=='A'){
       DNA.setCharAt(i,'T');
      }
      if(DNA.charAt(i)=='T'){
       DNA.setCharAt(i,'A');
      }
      if(DNA.charAt(i)=='G'){
       DNA.setCharAt(i,'C');
      }
      if(DNA.charAt(i)=='C'){
       DNA.setCharAt(i,'G');
      }
      }
    System.out.println(DNA);
       }
     }
```

So, thats my code right now. Its a basic program that takes a DNA strand, and gives its counterpart. However, certain letters will work while others wont. The conversion from T to A and C to G work, but the conversion from A to T and G to C do not. Can someone help me out?

Comment: You are creating a StringBuilder with the input from Scanner, then appending it to the StringBuilder again. Also a switch statement would be better

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code. It should take about two seconds to spot the problem.

Comment: Use `else if`s to prevent the next one from reversing the swap.

Answer (score 2):

Use `else if` statements to make it only switch the char once. Preferable to continue statements because you might, at a later time, put other logic at the end of the for loop.

```
for (int i=0;i<DNA.length();i++) {

        if (DNA.charAt(i)=='A'){

            DNA.setCharAt(i,'T');

        } else if (DNA.charAt(i)=='T'){

            DNA.setCharAt(i,'A');

        } else if (DNA.charAt(i)=='G'){

            DNA.setCharAt(i,'C');

        } else if (DNA.charAt(i)=='C'){

            DNA.setCharAt(i,'G');

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're ending up converting from A to T and then converting it back from T to A for the same iteration(character). Use `continue` to not go to the next condition if one is met.  -

```
for (int i = 0; i < DNA.length(); i++) {
    if (DNA.charAt(i) == 'A') {
        DNA.setCharAt(i, 'T');
        continue;
    }
    if (DNA.charAt(i) == 'T') {
        DNA.setCharAt(i, 'A');
        continue;
    }
    if (DNA.charAt(i) == 'G') {
        DNA.setCharAt(i, 'C');
        continue;
    }
    if (DNA.charAt(i) == 'C') {
        DNA.setCharAt(i, 'G');
        continue;
    }
}
```

This would produce the output as follows -

> ```
> What is the dna string?
> ATGC
>
> TACG
> ```

---

On a side note, you can get rid of the redundant `DNA.append( scan.nextLine());` before the loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing value from A to T in first `if` statement then in second `if` statement you are again changing it from T to A. Same thing you are doing for G to C.

Simple thing to fix is just add `break;` after `DNA.setCharAt(i,'YOUR_CHARS');`

or

use `else if` for 2nd, 3rd and 4th if statement.

or

use another variable to store result.